# WCF authentication via Kerberos on Windows XP

Tags: wcf, kerberos

I have got a .NET WCF client talking to a Java server component. Server-side authentication is done via an intermediate Apache server that is configured as a reverse proxy.

The .NET client has a configuration as follows:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="AdministrationServiceImplServiceSoapBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

The Apache is configured to require a Kerveros authentication:

```
<LocationMatch "^...$">
  AuthType Kerberos
  Krb5Keytab ...
  KrbServiceName HTTP/hostname
  KrbMethodNegotiate on
  KrbMethodK5Passwd off
  Require valid-user
  Satisfy All
</LocationMatch>
```

If I start my application on Windows 7, everything works as expected: the .NET client is using Kerberos, Apache authenticates the client, I can access the client credentials using Spring security.

If I start my application on Windows XP, I get an HTTP 401 error message. After watching the network communication using WireShark, I saw this happening:

(1) Initial attempt to access the web service without authentication

```
POST <path> HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Host: <host>
Content-Length: 374
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

(2) 100 Continue reply from server

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

(3) SOAP request from client (still unauthenticated)

(4) Server giving 401 response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Server: Apache
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

(5) Attempt of Client to use NTLM for authentication

```
POST <path> HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAt4IY4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFASgKAAAADw==
Host: <host>
Content-Length: 0
```

(6) 401 message from server (we don't speak NTLM here!)

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
```

(7) Client giving up

When I decode the Base64 negotiate header from the client, it starts with `NTLMSSP\x00` indicating that the client wants to do NTLM authentication despite of the configuration file specifying "Windows" (aka Kerberos) for the autentication.

Is there anything that I can do on the client side to persuade .NET to use Kerberos? If not, what should my Apache return so that the client knows it should use Kerberos?

Comment: I found a related SO question, but the answers there did not help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319001/why-is-kerberos-defaulting-to-ntlm-in-wcf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows did not use the correct service principal name (SPN) for the Kerberos-secured service: When using Kerberos, Windows should lookup the SPN `HTTP/$servername` in the active directory.

A possible cause of errors is that the SPN for the service does not exist and must be created (c.f. [Kerberos Authentication problems – Service Principal Name (SPN) issues - Part 3](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/09/kerberos-authentication-problems-service-principal-name-spn-issues-part-3.aspx)). In my setup, however, the SPN did exist, but somehow Windows did not retrieve them). Using [KerbTray](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23018) I verified that Windows did in fact not contain a Kerberos ticket for `HTTP/$servername`.

The solution was to explicitly define the SPN in the WCF client configuration.

```
<endpoint address="http://$servername/Service" />
```

became

```
<endpoint address="http://$servername/Service" />
  <identity>
    <servicePrincipalName value="HTTP/$servername" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```